# TypeError: Cannot read property of value between two getJSON functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, typeerror

When the length of my 2 json arrays are the same, I don't get an error. But when they aren't I get a `TypeError: Connot read property of undefined`.

JSON:

json1:

```javascript
[
    {
        "date": "2019-07-05",
        "x": 1246567,
        "y": 598045
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-07-06",
        "x": 1021607,
        "y": 452854
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-07-07",
        "x": 1031607,
        "y": 467854
    }
]
```

json2:

```php
[
    {
        "date": "2019-07-05",
        "v": 3132769,
        "pv": 6643094
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-07-06",
        "v": 2643611,
        "pv": 6059584
    }
]
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON(json1, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
       $('#x').text(elem.x);                            
       $('#y').text(elem.y);
});

$.getJSON(json2, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
    let yo = 0;
    if ((elem.date.indexOf(json[i].date) !== -1)) {
       yo = json[i].x/elem.v)
       $('#v').text(elem.v);                            
       $('#pv').text(elem.pv);
       $('#vpv').text(yo);  
    } 
   });
  });
```

Everything is ok when the length of the arrays match each other. But when one is longer than the other, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property x of undefined (at json[i].x).
```

I am even adding the condition

```
if ((elem.date.indexOf(json[i].date) !== -1)).
```

I thought that would fix that. But I am still getting the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see where you are defining "json", and trying to use json[i]. Are you sure you didn't mean to do json2[i] ?

Comment: I want the `yo = json[i].x/elem.v)` to only happen if the dates from json1 matches the date from json2

Comment: @ChrisShort, I want to use the x from json1 inside json2 to do yo = json[i].x/elem.v)

Comment: What exactly are `json1` and `json2`?  You're using them for `getJSON` which is an ajax request, so I would expect them to be strings...

Comment: @Taplar, they are json urls (external)

Comment: Ok, so you're making ajax requests.  How exactly is the second asynchronous request supposed to use the results of the first one, when the first one may not have finished yet?

Comment: well if the one is shorter than of course it will error since the second one has no data at that index. So you need to add logic in for that state.... Second issue is asynchronous requests....

Comment: @epascarello `if ((elem.date.indexOf(json[i].date) !== -1))` does not take care of that?

Comment: Not if `json` is undefined.  Again, this looks like an async issue.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `$('#x').text(elem.x);                            
       $('#y').text(elem.y);` makes no sense to loop because you are setting same element so it will only be the last entry.

Answer (score -1):

You need deal with asynchronous calls, you treat them like the are asynchronous. Since you are using jQuery, you can use `when()`

```
$.when(
  $.getJSON(url1),
  $.getJSON(url2)
).done(function(data1, data2) {
  console.log(data1[0]);
  console.log(data2[0]);
});
```

Now your logic is flawed for finding the matches. Personally I would combine them before working with the data

```js
const data1 = [{
    "date": "2019-07-05",
    "x": 1246567,
    "y": 598045
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-07-06",
    "x": 1021607,
    "y": 452854
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-07-07",
    "x": 1031607,
    "y": 467854
  }
]

const data2 = [{
    "date": "2019-07-05",
    "v": 3132769,
    "pv": 6643094
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-07-06",
    "v": 2643611,
    "pv": 6059584
  }
]

const dataPoints = data1.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.date] = item
  return obj
}, {})

data2.forEach(item => {
  //dataPoints[item.date] = dataPoints[item.date] || {}
  //Object.assign(dataPoints[item.date], item)
  dataPoints[item.date] = { ...(dataPoints[item.date] || {}),
    ...item
  }
})

Object.values(dataPoints).forEach(item => {
  console.group(item.date)
  if (item.x !== undefined && item.v !== undefined) {
    console.log(item.x / item.v);
  } else {
    console.log("can't do calc")
  }
  console.groupEnd(item.date)

})
```